# Filtering string, only allowing numbers, commas, brackets, and whitespace to pass

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to perform an if statement to filter some strings.

If the strings contain `0-9, whitespace, commas or brackets` I want to let them pass.
So this string should pass -

```
[[1,1],[2,3]]
```

However if the string was, say, `Hello World` or `[Hello World]` or `[1, $]` because they contain characters other than `0-9, whitespace, commas or brackets`

So what is the best way to do this?

Comment: REGEX, as you've tagged the question. Did you try a REGEX attempt?

Comment: I dont know the regex for it that's why I asked. Not knowing the regex for a particular operation is also the reason for the other 41665 regex related questions on stackoveflow.

Comment: Chill. SO's FAQs make clear a question should show code attempt or at least research effort. Yours shows neither, hence my reply. Otherwise, how do we distinguish your question from the thousands of others that come across simply as, "please do this for me"?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (preg_match("/[^\d\s,\[\]]/", $string)) {
    //Invalid
}
```